# Gradle: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I'm getting this compilation error in my XML file but I cant seem to spot the problem.. The error actually randomly came and I don't recall even touching this file but maybe I just cant see the problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context=".MyBetsWindow">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/AddBetButton"
        android:text="Add Bet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BetListLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By me, your code works ; the error doesn't come from your layout.

Here is what it's doing on a old program that I made called ABar:

[image: It Works !]

So check something else !